# Stop rest of UI elements events if AlertDialog is being shown

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

Guess it could also be asked as making an `AlertDialog` behave completely like a modal dialog.

I want to be able to display the `AlertDialog` and immediately stop everything on screen except the dialog buttons to stop reacting to any user action, so the button cannot be clicked, the checkbox cannot be checked and so on.

I know I could do this by, when the dialog is displayed, setting rest of element as not enabled, and when closing the dialog, setting them as enabled, but problem is dialogs may show or not depending on several factors, and there are a lot of elements to control which makes this way prone to error.

Maybe there's a more simple way in which the dialog is defined with some flag and by default fulfills that behavior.

I've already set the dialog with the modal flag this way, but it only helps in no closing the dialog if user taps outside of it without touching any other UI element (except for free space on layout), it still allows behaviour from other UI elements, like this:

```
dialog3.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);
```

Is there any way to do what I'm saying?

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure if this is the proper answer to your question. However, I can think of a workaround here.

I would like to suggest you keep a layout that overlaps the existing UI elements and hence stops the touching of those elements. Please take the following layout as an example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/input_mobile_number_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_mobile_number"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Mobile number"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:maxLength="11"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/input_mobile_number_layout"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:text="SUBMIT" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/overlap"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#80000000"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please check the `RelativeLayout` with id `overlap`.

So when you will be showing the `AlertDialog`, you need to make change the visibility of the `overlap` layout to `VISIBLE` and preventing other UI elements to be clicked. Then again, when you are dismissing the dialog, you need to make the `overlap` layout to `GONE`.

Please note that the `overlap` layout has a transparent background color to make this not very unusual. Also the default visibility is set to `GONE`.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

**Call this from the activity**

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
```

**To undo:**

```
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
```

**Alternative solution:**
Pass the root layout as the view

```
private static void setViewAndChildrenEnabled(View view, boolean enabled) {
    view.setEnabled(enabled);
    if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
        ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) view;
        for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View child = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
            setViewAndChildrenEnabled(child, enabled);
        }
    }
}
```